# Bluemix- Bind Mobilefirst Container to Cloud Foundry-App

Tags: mysql, ibm-mobilefirst, containers, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I created a MYSQL service and bound it to a cloud foundry application in Bluemix.
Now I created a Mobilefirst-Container.
How can I bind this container to the CF-App in order to get data from the database through the mobilefirst-Adapter?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the cloud foundry application when you create the container running one of the following commands (depending on the cli you are using for IBM containers):

```
$ cf ic run -p 80 -p 9080 -p 9443 --env CCS_BIND_APP=my_app --name my_container_name registry.ng.bluemix.net/ibm-mobilefirst-starter
```

or

```
$ ice run -p 80 -p 9080 -p 9443 --bind my_app --name my_container_name registry.ng.bluemix.net/ibm-mobilefirst-starter
```

Alternatively you can bind the application using the UI as well. In this case expand the **Advance Options** tab when creating the container in the UI. You will then see a **Service Binding** menu when you can select the cloud foundry application to bind to the container.

The application you bind to the container is called a **bridge application**. In the container you will not have access to the application itself, but only to the services bound to that application. You can access the services via the `VCAP_SERVICES` environment variable for the specific services.

More details in the documentation [here](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_creating_ov.html#container_single_cli).

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer.
I bind the container using the UI. I deployed my app and the SQL-Adapter to the worklight-Server(container). When i try to start the app, I get the following error in the Worklight-Logs: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not found in Worklight platform or project /MobileFirstStarter.

How can i upload the driver or how can I fix this?

Comment: This looks like a different question. I'd suggest you to ask a new question so someone from MobileFirstStarter team can help.